# CSS Table background colour for a table does not show in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background, html-table

Working in safari etc but not Chrome, I'm not an experienced programmer but slowly learning...

HTML

```
<table class="canvasbayheader" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
```

CSS

```
.canvasbayheader {
    background: #ed1c24;
}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle with all your code ... works for me http://jsfiddle.net/7a5Bh/

Comment: That will work just fine in Chrome. Make sure you table html is formed well.

Comment: Thanks for your replies i have also uploaded the text here not sure if you may see any problems, thanks in advance...

http://pastebin.com/pVWRppRq

Comment: its also only working in safari arghh, doesn't work in any other browser :(

Comment: I sm now using the following... anyone see any problems doing this ?
ps. not in css i dont think...

<table style="background-color:#ed1c24;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>

Comment: be sure to close alla your <td> etc..
Whats not working in other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely issues with your HTML table...

Copying your code in to a text editor, I get lines 33-36 look like this:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">


  </tr>
```

There is a `tr` closing tag immediately following a `table`, which is invalid.

I can see a few other instances where `td` and `tr` counts don't match...  specifically rows that aren't closed, etc.

I would go through the code and keep count of open tags, and make sure you close each one.

One more thing I've noticed - there are three tables on the page.  The first table is included in your php code, and if the condition is not met, there will only be two tables.   However, you still close all three tables in the code.   You will need to match the condition used at the top somewhere at the bottom, so your open and close tags all match up.

**UPDATE**

In response to your comments below, let me try and clear this up a bit more.   If I view the page you linked, and view the source code, here is some of what I'm seeing.

Line 106: Starts a new table, but did not close off the previous `tr`.  This is invalid.
Line 117: Starts a `td`, but there was no `tr` specified.   Also invalid.
Line 120: Starts a `td`, but the previous `td` was not closed out.

Obviously, these are the displayed lines in the View Source, so it may differ a bit from what you're seeing in your original source.   I would suggest opening your site in Firefox, right-clicking, select View Page Source, and using that as a reference.   You should be able to see the problems I'm describing here.

Comment: I can see what you mean but have no idea how to correct this, the page loads and looks right but as you say the code is odd and i cannot fathom out why, the web address is canvasbay.co.uk any idea what i can change i tried deleating the table line and it messed it all up maybe move the </tr> above the table line ?

Comment: I have for now just removed the </tr> tag is this okey now ? thanks

Comment: Ive seen your other comments and sadly think i am out of my depth and don't understand enough, as for the closing captions at the end of every line in the table is that were u hve to close the </tr> ? sorry for being dumb

Comment: `tr` is table row... `td` is table data...  Every `tr` will have one or more `td` included.  But you need to close each `<tr>` with a `</tr>` before starting the next `<tr>` (if that makes sense).

Comment: hanks fro the help, i shall try and edit the file now :)

Comment: I've updated the answer as well to try and demonstrate a couple areas I'm seeing problems...  hopefully it's helpful.   As the page is quite long, unfortunately I can't post EVERY mistake in the comments here... but hopefully that's a good starting point to see where your mistakes are and learn how to find them.

Comment: One more thing...  the issue you are seeing here is caused by the bad code...  but some browsers will "ignore" as much of the bad code as possible to try and figure out what you meant to code.   Each browser does this differently...  so if the code isn't perfect, you'll see different and unexpected results in each browser.

Comment: Also...  it sounds like you must not have a decent HTML editor that highlights these kinds of errors for you...  so try this to help.   I've copied your code in to a jsFiddle page here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8KvZ6/.    If you look at the code in the HTML section, every tag you see highlighted in red is bad.   Some of them may only be bad because an earlier error makes them so, so I would start at the very first error, and work my way down until all the red is gone.

Comment: I have tried well I have got it working now looks nice however can someone please check for errors with the tags not being closed etc ?  couple of pages not showing correct eg. buttons

Uploaded to.... http://pastebin.com/MSGst75i
Many thanks for any help.